# Why are formal and standoffish synonyms?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I recently saw the synonyms for Formal on Google and was wondering why standoffish is apart of it? Because being formal is being polite, while standoffish is unfriendly. What makes these two words synonyms oh and also here is a picture [image]

Comment: I suspect that there are hidden cultural factors in play here which you may be unaware of. If you would please be so kind as to share with us some general information about your region of origin, we may then be better able to address why this might appear to be a contradiction to you but not to others. For example, what is considered obligatory good manners in the American Deep South can be considered sassy and off-putting, sometimes even rude, only a thousand miles way—and vice versa. Even greater differences can be found between, say, Singapore and Seattle.

Answer (score 1):

In many situations there is nothing standoffish about being formal, but there are circumstances in which it can be. If one person want to establish an informal relationship and the other does not then insisting on formality is a way of being standoffish.

> He:    Oh let me call you Millicent, my dear, and you must call me Harry.
>
> She:   You may call me Miss Drinkwater, Sir.

The gentleman wants to establish a more intimate relationship but in insisting on formality Miss Millicent Drinkwater's attitude may be described as standoffish.